# Win32 Application calling C code

Tags: c++, c, winapi, user-interface

For my engineering project we are programming robots and our team decided to program a gui in Win32 to direct the robot how to move, rotate, etc. So far I haven't found anything on the web about how to encapsulate the code and call functions using buttons and other inputs. Anyone know of a good guide or any tips on how to do this?

Comment: This question is off topic. [Do some basic research](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and come back if you need to ask a specific question. Keep in mind that [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is your friend.

Comment: Umm.  MSDN would be a good start?

Comment: Does it have to be Win32? Not .NET?

Comment: @cowboydan I've worked with Win32 before but at this point it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Believe me, C# with the Visual Studio designer is a lot better suited for the task, and is fairly similar to C++. It's literally drop-drag, double-click, add code.

Comment: Please restate your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to program in the raw C/Win32 API, I'd get a copy of [Petzold](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X).  Buy a used copy ;)

If you want to program something more contemporary, I'd consider using C# and .Net.

IMHO...

PS:

You might also wish to consider Linux.  Linux can make it *really* easy to get close to the hardware, and you've got lots of choices in both languages (C, C++, Python, Java, etc etc) and UIs (SDL, Qt, GTK+, etc, etc)

Comment: Agreed. As a Microsoft C# alternative there are these really neat devices called Phidgets which allow a C#application to (via USB) control solenoids and other electromechanical devices. Www.phidgets.com

Answer (score 1):

Check out Qt.

This will allow you to easily create guis, connect click/mouse/any event to the underlying api call easily. Also allows you to trivially multi thread the application so that your calls to the underlying robot api will not lock up your front-end... all within one very easy to use and adaptable framework.

Imho, starting off with win32 is just asking for more pain than it's worth